# Enabling a Custom field using workflow in Acumatica 20R2

Tags: acumatica

I have to enable a custom field in Shipment screen in Complete status. I have tried to enable using the workflow in the customization package and it is not working.

[image]

I have inherited the workflow from default and added the custom field in field grid. After publishing the control for ref. no (UseRefNo) is not enabling.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

On top of enabling the field through different workflow states you can try and enable the field through code by extending the graph.

Documents in Completed status are closed and shouldn't be editable.
To re-enable any field you must at least re-enable the view:

```
Base.Document.AllowUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Please try   Base.Document.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;